# Ruby on Rails 6 AWS Elastic Beanstalk deploy Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sidekiq

I'm trying to update ruby and rails versions on aws. After I create a new environment on elastic beanstalk I tried to deploy updated version of rails project but it gives me `Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed` error. I couldn't figure out what caused it.

Here is the **cfn-init.log** file

```
2021-02-02 15:57:43,239 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2021-02-02 15:57:43,248 [INFO] Running configSets: _OnInstanceBoot
2021-02-02 15:57:43,252 [INFO] Running configSet _OnInstanceBoot
2021-02-02 15:57:43,257 [INFO] Running config AWSEBBaseConfig
2021-02-02 15:57:43,499 [INFO] Command clearbackupfiles succeeded
2021-02-02 15:57:43,503 [INFO] Running config AWSEBCfnHupEndpointOverride
2021-02-02 15:57:43,510 [INFO] Command clearbackupfiles succeeded
2021-02-02 15:57:43,511 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2021-02-02 15:57:43,511 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2021-02-02 15:57:46,805 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2021-02-02 15:57:46,840 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-02-02 15:57:46,848 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-02-02 15:57:46,853 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_myapp_com
2021-02-02 15:57:46,855 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2021-02-02 15:57:46,855 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2021-02-02 15:57:57,735 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2021-02-02 15:57:57,743 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2021-02-02 15:57:57,747 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2021-02-02 15:57:57,748 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2021-02-02 15:57:57,748 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2021-02-02 15:59:12,848 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2021-02-02 15:59:12,857 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-02-02 15:59:12,861 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-02-02 15:59:12,866 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_myapp_com
2021-02-02 15:59:12,873 [INFO] Running config prebuild_1_myapp_com
2021-02-02 15:59:12,880 [INFO] Running config prebuild_2_myapp_com
2021-02-02 15:59:12,884 [ERROR] Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq (initctl reload-configuration) failed
2021-02-02 15:59:12,884 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_2_myapp_com: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
2021-02-02 15:59:12,886 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2021-02-02 15:59:12,886 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 129, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 530, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
2021-02-03 11:21:36,581 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2021-02-03 11:21:36,590 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-02-03 11:21:36,594 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-02-03 11:21:36,600 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_myapp_com
2021-02-03 11:21:36,606 [INFO] Running config prebuild_1_myapp_com
2021-02-03 11:21:36,613 [INFO] Running config prebuild_2_myapp_com
2021-02-03 11:21:36,614 [INFO] Symbolic link /etc/init/sidekiq.conf already exists
2021-02-03 11:21:36,617 [ERROR] Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq (initctl reload-configuration) failed
2021-02-03 11:21:36,618 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_2_myapp_com: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
2021-02-03 11:21:36,618 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2021-02-03 11:21:36,618 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 129, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 530, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
2021-02-03 11:28:00,490 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2021-02-03 11:28:00,499 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-02-03 11:28:00,503 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-02-03 11:28:00,508 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_myapp_com
2021-02-03 11:28:00,515 [INFO] Running config prebuild_1_myapp_com
2021-02-03 11:28:00,522 [INFO] Running config prebuild_2_myapp_com
2021-02-03 11:28:00,523 [INFO] Symbolic link /etc/init/sidekiq.conf already exists
2021-02-03 11:28:00,526 [ERROR] Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq (initctl reload-configuration) failed
2021-02-03 11:28:00,527 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_2_myapp_com: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
2021-02-03 11:28:00,527 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2021-02-03 11:28:00,527 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 129, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 530, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
2021-02-03 12:59:49,252 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2021-02-03 12:59:49,262 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-02-03 12:59:49,267 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-02-03 12:59:49,272 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_myapp_com
2021-02-03 12:59:49,279 [INFO] Running config prebuild_1_myapp_com
2021-02-03 12:59:49,286 [INFO] Running config prebuild_2_myapp_com
2021-02-03 12:59:49,287 [INFO] Symbolic link /etc/init/sidekiq.conf already exists
2021-02-03 12:59:49,290 [ERROR] Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq (initctl reload-configuration) failed
2021-02-03 12:59:49,290 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_2_myapp_com: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
2021-02-03 12:59:49,291 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2021-02-03 12:59:49,291 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 129, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 530, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command reload_initctl_for_sidekiq failed
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you fix the issue??

Comment: Nope unfortunately :(

Comment: Same here, can't even find a detailed log.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that somewhere in your configs you were using `initctl`. You need to replace it with `systemctl` for Amazon Linux 2. There can be other outdated commands as well, so you will need to fix them by trying multiple times.

I know it has been quite some time since this question was asked. I encountered the same problem when I was working on an old project.